# Added a functions_copy.php file to my child theme, tried to change name to function.php but keep getting this error. How do I fix this?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, parse-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/46/8832746/html/wp-content/themes/gmr/functions.php on line 38

Answer (score 0):

It appears in your functions_copy.php you are missing an ending } somewhere, i would walk through your code step by step and make sure you have an ending } top each starting {.

Comment: thanks @battletoilet I've just received some help from a friend of mine on fb, he pointed out the same thing. Something as simple as that ey... cheers either way.